# Search and replace files and folders names with txt file support

Tags: powershell

I have many folders and inside these different files. Each folder and their children files have the same name and different extension, so in the ABC folder there are the ABC.png, ABC.prj, ABC.pgw files, in the DEF folder there are the DEF.png, DEF.prj, DEF.pgw files and so on.
With a script I have created a txt file with the list of png file names. Then I put in row 2 a new name for the name in row1, in row 4 a new name for the name in row 3, and so on. 
Now I'm searching a powershell script that:
- scan all folder for the name in row 1 and replace it with name in row2
- scan all folder for the name in row 3 and replace it with name in row4 and so on

I have try with this below, but it doesn't work.

Have you some suggestions? Thank you

```
$0=0
$1=1
do {
$find=Get-Content C:\1\Srv\MapsName.txt | Select -Index $0
$repl=Get-Content C:\1\Srv\MapsName.txt | Select -Index $1
Get-ChildItem C:\1\newmaps -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $find, $repl} -verbose
$0=$0+2
$1=$1+2
}
until ($0 -eq "")
```

Comment: Sorry it took a while, but I was out a couple of days. I have added a new answer to your question using a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are several things wrong with your code and also the code Manuel gave you.

1. Although you have a list of old filenames and new filenames, you are not using that in the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, but instead try and replace all files it finds.
2. Using `-replace` uses a Regular Expression replace, that means the special character `.` inside the filename is regarded as `Any Character`, not simply a dot.
3. You are trying to find `*.png` files, but you do not add a `-Filter` with the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, so now it will return all filetypes.

Anyway, I have a different approach for you:

If your input file `C:\1\Srv\MapsName.txt` looks anything like this:

```
picture1.png
ABC_1.png
picture2.png
DEF_1.png
picture3.png
DEF_2.png
```

The following code will use that to build a lookup Hashtable so it can act on the files mentioned in the input file and leave all others unchanged.

```
$mapsFile   = 'C:\1\Srv\2_MapsName.txt'
$searchPath = 'C:\1\NewMaps'

# Read the input file as an array of strings.
# Every even index contains the file name to search for. 
# Every odd index number has the new name for that file.
$lines = Get-Content $mapsFile

# Create a hashtable to store the filename to find
# as Key, and the replacement name as Value
$lookup = @{}
for ($index = 0; $index -lt $lines.Count -1; $index += 2) {
    $lookup[$lines[$index]] = $lines[$index + 1]
}

# Next, get a collection of FileInfo objects of *.png files
# If you need to get multiple extensions, remove the -Filter and add -Include '*.png','*.jpg' etc.
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Filter '*.png' -File -Recurse

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # If the file name can be found as Key in the $lookup Hashtable
    $find = $file.Name
    if ($lookup.ContainsKey($find)) {
        # Rename the file with the replacement name in the Value of the lookup table
        Write-Host "Renaming '$($file.FullName)' -->  $($lookup[$find])"
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName $lookup[$find]
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If the input text file 'C:\1\Srv\MapsName.txt' does NOT contain filenames including their extension, change the final `foreach` loop into this:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # If the file name can be found as Key in the $lookup Hashtable
    # Look for the file name without extension as it is not given in the 'MapsName.txt' file.
    $find = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name)
    if ($lookup.ContainsKey($find)) {
        # Rename the file with the replacement name in the Value of the lookup table
        # Make sure to add the file's extension if any.
        $newName = $lookup[$find] + $file.Extension
        Write-Host "Renaming '$($file.FullName)' --> '$newName'"
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. This night I wiil try the script. The MapsName.txt contains lines like:
`423423_ABC_54  <br/>
ABC 54  <br/>
895293_79_DFG  <br/>
DFG 112  <br/>
...`

Comment: @Marco I hope those `<br/>` are in fact real newlines! I have added new code to my answer to deal with the fact that you do not include the file extensions in the input file. Perhaps, it is wise to add a `-WhatIf` parameter to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet the first time you try this out.

Comment: <br/> is my proof to get linebreacks in the comment above, unsuccessfully :( I edit the line: `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchPath -Recurse | sort name -descending` and everything works perfectly and at supersonic speed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your snippet is that it never ends.
I tried it and it works but keeps looping forever.
I created a folder with the files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt.
And in the map.txt I have this content:

```
a.txt
a2.md
b.txt
b2.md
c.txt
c2.md
```

Running the following script I managed to rename every file to be as expected.

```
$0=0
$1=1

$find=Get-Content D:\map.txt | Select -Index $0
while($find) {
    $find=Get-Content D:\map.txt | Select -Index $0
    $repl=Get-Content D:\map.txt | Select -Index $1

    if(!$find -Or !$repl) {
        break;
    }

    Get-ChildItem D:\Files -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $find, $repl} -verbose
    $0=$0+2
    $1=$1+2
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for the code and explanation.

Comment: I was thinking that my solution is not ideal, you should use a while loop not do until.
In your code the real issue is that you are trying to stop the loop checking if $0 is equal to empty string, but this is never true, because it is always an integer incremented forever.
So I will update my answer to implement a while loop.

Comment: Thank you for all, tomorrow I will try it on real stuff.

Comment: Why so many `Get-Content`. You only need to do that once and go through the array by index. Something like `$lines = Get-Content "D:\map.txt"`. Next use as `$lines[$0]`, `$lines[$1]` etc.

Comment: @Theo I can't implement your suggestion, where is my error?:
`$0=0  
$1=1

$lines=Get-Content C:\1\Srv\2_MapsName.txt
while($find) {
    $find=$lines[$0]
    $repl=$lines[$1]

    if(!$find -Or !$repl) {
        break;
    }

    Get-ChildItem C:\1\NewMaps -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $find, $repl} #-verbose
    $0=$0+2
    $1=$1+2
}`,

Comment: After a long long list of errors: `The source path can not match the destination path.` files and folder are rightly renamed. 
`Rename-Item : Il percorso di origine non può coincidere con quello di destinazione.
In riga:7 car:43
+ ... Maps -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $find, $repl}
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\1\NewMaps\Va...SO 4L137(ex116):String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand`